# xpath - how to select multiple nodes based on value

Tags: xml, xpath

I have some xml and I would like to dynamically extract some information, based on some incoming data.

Here is some xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<releaseNote>
 <name>DECOUPLING_client</name>
  <change>
   <date hour="12" day="24" second="44" year="2012" month="10" minute="46"/>
   <submitter>Automatically Generated</submitter>
   <description>ReleaseNote Created</description>
  </change>
  <change>
   <version>0-2</version>
   <date hour="12" day="24" second="48" year="2012" month="11" minute="46"/>
   <submitter>fred.darwin</submitter>
   <description> first iteration of decoupling client - copied files from old decoupling module</description>
   <install/>
  </change>
 <change>
  <version>0-3</version>
  <date hour="16" day="25" second="34" year="2012" month="11" minute="52"/>
  <submitter>fred.darwin</submitter>
  <description> promoting changes</description>
  <install/>
 </change>
</releaseNote>
```

And I'd like to pass in the string '0-2' and find out all versions *since* 0-2 like this:

```
0-3     fred.darwin       25/11/2012      promoting changes
```

It's complicated by the fact that the numbers I'm comparing start with '0-'.

However luckily you can remove the '0-' and get a real number, which corresponds to a position, so I've got as far as something like this:

```
xmllint --xpath '/releaseNote/change[position()>2]/description/text() ${file}
```

which just concatenates all the descriptions and spits them out.

How do I loop through them and select multiple node content?

Comment: Well, xmllint does just serialize the result. How would you like to get back multiple results, if not concatenated together, if they are just serialized?

Comment: Are versions ordered in the XML serialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I got it working like this:

```
#first count number of nodes ie how many changes (could be eg 979)
numChanges=`xmllint --xpath 'count(/releaseNote/change)' ${MPATH}/${mod}/resources/ReleaseNote.xml`
echo "found $numChanges changes"
#even though last one shows as 0-952
lastModule=`xmllint --xpath '/releaseNote/change[last()]/version/text()' ${MPATH}/${mod}/resources/ReleaseNote.xml`
#so

#then loop through from our one to the end
#use a unix loop
echo "version number ${versionNumber} num changes ${numChanges}"
#for i in {${versionNumber}..${numChanges}}; do
i=$versionNumber
while [[ $i -le $numChanges ]]  ; do
#and for each item in the list spit out description, version, submitter and try to parse date
xmllint --xpath "/releaseNote/change[$i]/version/text()" ${MPATH}/${mod}/resources/ReleaseNote.xml
echo -en ' \t '
xmllint --xpath "string(/releaseNote/change[$i]/date/@day)" ${MPATH}/${mod}/resources/ReleaseNote.xml
echo -en '/'
xmllint --xpath "string(/releaseNote/change[$i]/date/@month)" ${MPATH}/${mod}/resources/ReleaseNote.xml
echo -en '/'
xmllint --xpath "string(/releaseNote/change[$i]/date/@year)" ${MPATH}/${mod}/resources/ReleaseNote.xml
echo -en ' '
xmllint --xpath "string(/releaseNote/change[$i]/date/@hour)" ${MPATH}/${mod}/resources/ReleaseNote.xml
echo -en ':'
xmllint --xpath "string(/releaseNote/change[$i]/date/@minute)" ${MPATH}/${mod}/resources/ReleaseNote.xml
echo -en ' \t '
xmllint --xpath "/releaseNote/change[$i]/submitter/text()" ${MPATH}/${mod}/resources/ReleaseNote.xml
echo -en ' \t '
xmllint --xpath "/releaseNote/change[$i]/description/text()" ${MPATH}/${mod}/resources/ReleaseNote.xml
((i = i + 1))
echo
done
```

Output looks like this:

```
0-96     21/4/2014 17:56     onkar.sharma     test case for subscription validation
0-97     28/5/2014 15:58     trushant.patel       JIRAET81
0-98     9/6/2014 18:10      vivek.mittal     Refinement for GetFindPackagesWithService flow
```

It's much slower than when I was using grep and tr, but it does allow me to parse the date correctly and it looks exactly as I wanted.

Success!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you already found a solution, but just to offer an alternative: if you don't mind using XSLT, you could also have an stylesheet file like this:

#### stylesheet.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"/>

  <xsl:param name="version"/>

  <!-- Strip white-space-only text nodes in all elements -->
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:variable name="version-after-hyphen" select="number(substring-after($version, '-'))"/>

  <!-- XML entity for a tab -->
  <xsl:variable name="DELIMITER" select="'&#9;'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!--
    Apply every <change> element with a <version> child whose value is $version
    or greater.
    -->
    <xsl:apply-templates
      select="releaseNote/change[number(substring-after(version, '-')) &gt;= $version-after-hyphen]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="change">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <!-- Insert a newline after every <change> element -->
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="submitter | description">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($DELIMITER, normalize-space(.))"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="version">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="date">
    <!-- Format date -->
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($DELIMITER, @day, '/', @month, '/', @year, ' ', @hour, ':', @minute)"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could then run it with `xsltproc` e.g. like this:

```
xsltproc --stringparam version 0-2 stylesheet.xsl releaseNote.xml
```

And the output would be:

```
0-2 24/11/2012 12:46  fred.darwin first iteration of decoupling client - copied files from old decoupling module
0-3 25/11/2012 16:52  fred.darwin promoting changes
```

I'm fairly certain it'll be faster than executing `xmllint` multiple times and perhaps somewhat easier to maintain in the long run as well. `libxml2` (which you already have installed since you have `xmllint`) includes `xsltproc`, too, so that shouldn't be a problem, either.